# Create folders based on filenames bash

Tags: server

Need to create a folder for each Customer and then move all the logs into that directory.

Example.

Filenames:

> John.Luca.010101.txt
>
> John.Luca.010102.txt
>
> John.Luca.010103.txt
>
> John.Luca.Jr.010101.txt
>
> John.Luca.Jr.010102.txt

Need to create a folder named John.Luca and another named John.Luca.Jr and then move all the logs for each Customer.

> John.Luca/John.Luca.010101.txt
>
> John.Luca/John.Luca.010102.txt
>
> John.Luca.Jr/John.Luca.Jr.010101.txt

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  [[ ! -d "${f%.*.*}" ]] && mkdir "${f%.*.*}"
  mv "$f" "${f%.*.*}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm!